# Can't tell if bytecode instrumentation is working in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

I am using the example below:
https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-4-bytecode-enhancement/

for the bytecode ehancement. I am building the content fine but the compiled code is unchanged. i used a decompiler to view the file and it is the same.
How do i know if the bytecode is working?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-enable-bytecode-enhancement-dirty-checking-in-hibernate/), the bytecode enhancement plugin didn't work properly prior to Hibernate 5.

More, make sure that your IDE does not overwrite (by recompiling the source code) the classes which were previously enhanced by running the instrumentation task.